# Indexes in functions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've read that the major difference between views and normal queries in SQL Server is that view can take advantage of indexing while normal queries don't. 
For the same reason I've tried my best to use indexing as much as I can and create views instead of making normal queries either in SQL or LINQ (could be slower). But sometimes I need to pass parameters to the query which I normally do in LINQ. Now I just learned that I can write Funcions in SQL to create parameterized views.

My question is, do functions takes advantage of the indexing too ? (if what I've read on views vs queries is right).

Comment: queries take advantages of indexes.

Comment: @Laurence: Then what comes to my mind is that, what would be the difference between them again?

Comment: Also be careful with functions if your function is supposed to return large data set, for large data set use stored procedure

Comment: views might be more convenient if you are using the same definitions over and over again. Also, you can grant permissions on them separately to the base tables.

Comment: Something useful would be to learn to use SQL Profiler to capture the queries that are running (on a dev/test system), and the view execution plan feature of SSMS. You might not understand everything in the plans at first, but it's fairly clear if you hover over the nodes if indexes are being used or not.

Comment: http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-wrong-optimizations/#opt5